# How to Shorted Regular Expression

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

I have a RegExp as below, when I use it in Oracle SQL, I got ORA-12723 error, how can I let it in the shortest format?

```
WITH test_data ( str ) AS (
    SELECT 'This is extension 1234, here is mobile phone: 090-1234-5678 maybe 8+24-98765432. Then +1-(234)-090-345 also 86 21-4566-4556' AS str FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TRIM(
    TRAILING ',' FROM
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
       str,
       '.*?(\+?\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{3,11}|\+?\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{3,11}|\+?\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{3,11}|\+?\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{3,11}|\+?\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{3,11}|\d{3,11}|$)',
       '\1,'
    )
) AS replaced_str
FROM test_data
```

The result what I wonder as below:

```
1234,090-1234-5678,8+24-98765432,+1-(234)-090-345,86 21-4566-4556
```

Comment: What do you like to achieve with your Regex?

Comment: How would some matches look?

Comment: I want match all phone number with different format, they can be 3-11 digits with other characters between numbers.

Comment: `select regexp_substr` with your regexp works for me in my oracle. What version of oracle do you have and what command do you use to apply the regexp?

Comment: I updated my question, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach.  This uses `CONNECT BY` to traverse the string and parse it into elements that are separated by a space or the end of the line.  Then for each element, remove non-digit characters `('\D')`.  Lastly use `LISTAGG()` to put the elements back into one comma delimited string.

```
WITH test_data(str) AS (
    SELECT 'Txa233g141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147zz Ta233xx148zz' AS str FROM DUAL
)
SELECT listagg(regexp_replace(regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, level, null, 1), '\D'), ',') 
         within group (order by str) replaced_str
FROM test_data
connect by level <= regexp_count(str, ' ') + 1;


REPLACED_STR                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
233141,233141,233142,233147,233148    

1 row selected.
```

Comment: I need to shorted this RegExp `.*?(\+?\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{3,11}|\+?\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{3,11}|\+?\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{3,11}|\+?\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{3,11}|\+?\d{1,11}[-,\+]\d{3,11}|\d{3,11}|$)`..., data above just sample, not real data...

Comment: Show the real data,and what you expect it to look like after processing. Update your original post.

Comment: Or, did you try plugging real data into my solution?  Did it work?

Comment: Updated with my question.

Comment: Ok, replace the string in my example with the new test data, and change the delimiter in my example to be a comma instead of a space in both places.